# Subscribe to a control's event on another form in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I have a main Window in my WPF application that has a frame as a child element. The code behind a button on the main window navigates to a URI(page) within the frame. The navigated page is not the child of the frame or the main window. The page has a data grid that I would like to refresh when a button on the main window is clicked. I have been trying to figure out without any luck on how to trigger an update on the grid when the button is clicked essentially pass the value of a text box from the main form to a method on the grid, that is on a different parent. Can someone please guide me or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Guessing you have databound the grid [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676202/how-to-force-a-wpf-binding-to-refresh) may help

Comment: Are you using the MVVM pattern?

Comment: Hi voddy and Paulo, No I am not using MVVM since this is a very small app and it is a bit of learning curve for me. I thought I would learn wpf and xaml first before I learn how to structure the app with MVVM.