# Update Binding in Windows Phone Runtime app

Tags: c#, listview, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to modify some items from a `ListView` on my Windows Phone RunTime app.

The Items are binded to the ListView by a simple binding:

```
this.defaultViewModel["myBinding"] = pi;
```

and in xaml:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding myBinding}" ... >
```

Then, I'm modifying the binding from code:

```
        List<myItem> pi = (List<myItem>)this.defaultViewModel["myBinding"];
        pi.RemoveAt(5);
```

Now, I want to update the UI with the new modified `pi`. I know that `this.defaultViewModel["myBinding"] = null;` and then `this.defaultViewModel["myBinding"] = pi;` works, but it doesn't keep the scroll position of ListView (it jumps to top after doing this).

Also I have tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5676257/942659), but seems that `UpdateTarget` is not available in Windows Phone RunTime apps.

So, what should I do to force refresh `ItemsSource` of my `ListView`, without losing it's scroll position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `ObservableCollection<myItem>` instead of `List<myItem>`. Then you won't need to unset and set the list to update the ListView.

To scroll to an item in a ListView with a `ListView listView`, you can call `listView.ScrollIntoView(item)`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't get `ScrollIntoView` working. neither `myListView.ScrollIntoView(pi[7]);` nor `myListView.ScrollIntoView(myListView.Items[7]);` works. Can you help?

Comment: Try adding `listView.UpdateLayout()` before you call ScrollIntoView

Comment: Oh. I'm sorry. I missed your point about `ObservableCollection`. With the use of `ObservableCollection`, I don't need to set the binding to `null` and `pi` again. So I don't need `ScrollIntoView` at all. It does everything automatically. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Need to Implement INofityPropertyChanged

[MSDN: inotifypropertychanged Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Sample from the MSDN article:

```
public class DemoCustomer : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property. 
    // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName 
    // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument. 
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private DemoCustomer()
    {
    }

    private string customerNameValue = String.Empty;
    public string CustomerName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.customerNameValue;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != this.customerNameValue)
            {
                this.customerNameValue = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```