# How make a ListBox update when the field of a certain AvaloniaList element changes?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, avalonia

Recently started studying C#, making a project using AvaloniaUI, ReactiveUI and a MVVM pattern.

The essence of the problem is as follows: there is an AvaloniaList(observable collection), a ListBox is bound to it by binding.

MainWindow.axaml:

```
 <ListBox Items="{Binding Devices}" 
     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDevice}" 
     SelectionMode="Single, Toggle">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
       <StackPanel Margin="5">
         <TextBlock FontSize="18" Text="{Binding name}" />
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding state}" />
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding ip}" />
       </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

ViewModels:

```
private AvaloniaList<Device>? devices;
public AvaloniaList<Device> Devices
{
  get => devices;
  set
  {
    devices = value;
    this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref devices, value);
  }
}

How can I make a ListBox update when the field of a certain AvaloniaList element changes?

So far I see only one option: to clear and re-fill the collection, but I would like to avoid this.
```

Comment: Maybe this is what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676202/how-to-force-a-wpf-binding-to-refresh

Comment: Thank you, but this is not exactly what helps to solve the problem

Comment: You should start with creating a view model for Device and use it in your list

Answer (score 0):

if a device name changed it should be updated automatically in case the Device class also implement the INotifyPropertyChanged
so check if "Name" property in "Device" Class has RaiseAndSetIfChanged

edit:
if you can't change the class Device you need to make sure to raise property changed on the Devices list when updating a value

Comment: This will work if binding to a specific class field
All fields of the class implement RaiseAndSetIfChanged, but the list is updated only when an element is added or removed, and not when it is changed
Now I am deleting the element and putting the modified one in its place, but this is not a solution, but a crutch

Comment: how about my edit suggestion ?, call notifypropertychanged on devices (not if changed)